# how to delete the data from sqlite populated in lisview

Tags: android-sqlite

I am using sqlite and there is a problem while delete data from sqlite which is populated in listview.There is no error in logcat. Id of selected item is toast.But can't delete the data from database.
if i delete each row one by one then data is not found there but when i add some new data after that deleted data is also there.
when i click the button named viewinfo last entry is repeated in listview.

this is the code to delete data from sqlite which is stored in listview

```
 public Integer deleteData(String position){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(Table_N," ID = ? ",new String[]{position});

    }
```

this is the code to delete data from listview

```
public void viewinformation() {
        dataKASPER.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = dataKASPER.getAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "data is not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                Names_araylist.add(cursor.getString(1).toString());

                Designation_arraylist.add(cursor.getString(2).toString());
                 adapter=new lisadapter(Infolist.this,Names_araylist,Designation_arraylist);

                mlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                mlistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                mlistview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Infolist.this,Viewallinfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,  long l) {
        final String id= String.valueOf(l);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Warning");
        builder.setMessage("Want You Delete This Record??");

        builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dataKASPER.deleteData(id);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(Infolist.this,id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                builder.setCancelable(true);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }
```

please tell me how i can delete the data from database properly.

Comment: please give me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the issue is that you are trying to delete a Name using a numeric value.

That is **`l`** (the long) as passed into the `onItemLongClick` method, is the **`_id`** column for the respective row, which you use to assign to the string variable **`id`** and then pass to the `deleteData` method.

This tries to delete the row that has **`Name`** as the id, (i.e. the rows _id column value). The fix, would appear to be to change:-

`return db.delete(Table_N," Name = ? ",new String[]{position});`

to

**`return db.delete(Table_N," _id = ? ",new String[]{position});`**

i.e. delete the row who's _id column is the value of the _id passed into the `onItemLongClick` method.

---

**Edited as per the comment that there is no _id in the table** :-

OK, then **l** is basically useless as per

> id    long: The row id of the item that was clicked

from [AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html).

You would need to determine and extract **Name** via position. **l** and thus **id** will very likely not ever be the **Name** and hence why it would be unlikely that using **l** would result in any row being deleted.

How you utilise position would depend upon the data source fed into the adapter be it an array or a cursor.  **position** would either be the respective array index or the respective position within the cursor. Alternately you may also be able to utilise getSelectedItem(), which retrieves

> The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if
>   there is nothing selected

as an object. from [AdapterView - getSelectedItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

However, using `return db.delete(Table_N," Name = ? ",new String[]{position});` could result in multiple rows being deleted if Name isn't unique.

Another option that I haven't tested is to use **rowid** (which every table has unless WITHOUT ROWID is coded) (this is if **l** gets rowid if _id isn't present, which is the aspect that I haven't tested).

> **ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY**
>
> Except for WITHOUT ROWID tables, all rows within SQLite tables have a
>   64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its
>   table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". The rowid value can
>   be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid",
>   "oid", or "*rowid*" in place of a column name. If a table contains a
>   user defined column named "rowid", "oid" or "*rowid*", then that name
>   always refers the explicitly declared column and cannot be used to
>   retrieve the integer rowid value.
>   from [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Assuming that **l** does return the respective `rowid` then coding `return db.delete(Table_N," rowid = ? ",new String[]{position});` would work.

If the adpapter's data source is a Cursor then you could create _id as an alias of rowid, and thus the above could then work. e.g. `SELECT Name, rowid AS _id FROM yourtable`.

If the adapter's data source is an array then utilising `rowid` isn't an option.

Editing your question to include the code that instantiates the adapter and the code that creates the data source would enable a more specific answer to be given.

---

## Regarding comment on 4th July :-

Here's some basic code that does does what you want, but uses a simple adapter:-

First the layout (**activity_main.xml** which just has a ListView i.e. nothing special here):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.so44730629.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The **DBHelper**, note that I've included various methods, such as ones that return String ArrayLists :-

```
public class dataKasper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final static String DBDATABASENAME = "kasper";
    public final static int DBVERSION = 1;

    public final static String DBTABLENAME = "Table_N";
    public final static String DBIDCOLNAME = "ID";
    public final static String DBNAMECOLNAME = "Name";

    public final static String DBCREATESQL = "CREATE TABLE " +
            DBTABLENAME + "(" +
            DBIDCOLNAME + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            DBNAMECOLNAME + " TEXT" +
            ");";

    public final static String DBORDERBYID = DBIDCOLNAME;
    private int tcount;

    public dataKasper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBDATABASENAME,null,DBVERSION);
        tcount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DBCREATESQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int newversion, int oldversion) {
    }

    public void deleteData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause =  DBIDCOLNAME + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{Long.toString(id)};
        db.delete(DBTABLENAME,whereclause,whereargs);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteDataByName(String Name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = DBNAMECOLNAME + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{Name};
        db.delete(DBTABLENAME,whereclause,whereargs);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor rv = db.query(DBTABLENAME,null,null,null,null,null,DBORDERBYID);
        tcount = rv.getCount();
        return rv;
    }

    public int getAllRowCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor allrows = db.query(DBTABLENAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        int rv = allrows.getCount();
        allrows.close();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public void insertRow(String Name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBNAMECOLNAME,Name);
        db.insert(DBTABLENAME,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor alldata = getAllData();
        while (alldata.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(alldata.getString(alldata.getColumnIndex(DBNAMECOLNAME)));
        }
        alldata.close();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllIDS() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor alldata = getAllData();
        while (alldata.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(alldata.getString(alldata.getColumnIndex(DBIDCOLNAME)));
        }
        alldata.close();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Finally the **Activity** (**`MainActivity.java`**) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    dataKasper dbhelper = new dataKasper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        if (dbhelper.getAllRowCount() < 1) {
            dbhelper.insertRow("Fred");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Bert");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Harry");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Mary");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Anne");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Fred"); // DUPLICATE NAME but different ID
            dbhelper.insertRow("Ronald");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Bert"); // DUPLICATE NAME
            dbhelper.insertRow("Tom");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Mike");
        }

        names = dbhelper.getAllNames();
        ids = dbhelper.getAllIDS();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // Get the associated ID according to the position
                dbhelper.deleteData(Long.parseLong(ids.get(i)));
                names.remove(i);
                ids.remove(i);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The important/relevant aspects being in the LongClick Listener.

a) The ID of the row to be deleted is obtained by accessing the ids ArrayList whoose elements match the respective element in the names ArrayList. i.e. element 10 of the ids ArrayList will be the id for the respective Names (This copes with duplicated names).

b) before calling the adapters `notifyDataSetChanged` the ArrayLists are aligned with the data in the database. i.e. the respective elements are removed (NOTE! this will not handle with a failed delete) using lines `names.remove(i);` and `ids.remove(i);`.

Note! Ideally the column **ID** should be named **_id** (CursorAdapters need an **_id** column, which is personally what I'd use.)

It should be relatively simple to adapt the above to use your adapter.

---

## Comparing Cursor/with Array Adapters

Here's code that utilises both Cursor and Array adapters with two ListViews (one for each) so you can compare the two methodlogies:-

The layout (with a second Listview) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.so44730629.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The dataKasper DBHelper (Now uses **_id** not ID):-

```
public class dataKasper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final static String DBDATABASENAME = "kasper";
    public final static int DBVERSION = 1;

    public final static String DBTABLENAME = "Table_N";
    public final static String DBIDCOLNAME = "_id";
    public final static String DBNAMECOLNAME = "Name";

    public final static String DBCREATESQL = "CREATE TABLE " +
            DBTABLENAME + "(" +
            DBIDCOLNAME + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            DBNAMECOLNAME + " TEXT" +
            ");";

    public final static String DBORDERBYID = DBIDCOLNAME;
    private int tcount;

    public dataKasper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBDATABASENAME,null,DBVERSION);
        tcount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DBCREATESQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int newversion, int oldversion) {
    }

    public void deleteData(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause =  DBIDCOLNAME + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{Long.toString(id)};
        db.delete(DBTABLENAME,whereclause,whereargs);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteDataByName(String Name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = DBNAMECOLNAME + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{Name};
        db.delete(DBTABLENAME,whereclause,whereargs);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor rv = db.query(DBTABLENAME,null,null,null,null,null,DBORDERBYID);
        tcount = rv.getCount();
        return rv;
    }

    public int getAllRowCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor allrows = db.query(DBTABLENAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        int rv = allrows.getCount();
        allrows.close();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public void insertRow(String Name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBNAMECOLNAME,Name);
        db.insert(DBTABLENAME,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor alldata = getAllData();
        while (alldata.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(alldata.getString(alldata.getColumnIndex(DBNAMECOLNAME)));
        }
        alldata.close();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllIDS() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor alldata = getAllData();
        while (alldata.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(alldata.getString(alldata.getColumnIndex(DBIDCOLNAME)));
        }
        alldata.close();
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

And finally the new Activity (of course you wouldn't normally have both together):-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    dataKasper dbhelper = new dataKasper(this);
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv2 = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);

        if (dbhelper.getAllRowCount() < 1) {
            dbhelper.insertRow("Fred");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Bert");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Harry");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Mary");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Anne");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Fred"); // DUPLICATE NAME but different ID
            dbhelper.insertRow("Ronald");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Bert"); // DUPLICATE NAME
            dbhelper.insertRow("Tom");
            dbhelper.insertRow("Mike");
        }

        names = dbhelper.getAllNames();
        ids = dbhelper.getAllIDS();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // Get the associated ID according to the position
                dbhelper.deleteData(Long.parseLong(ids.get(i)));
                names.remove(i);
                ids.remove(i);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });

        cursor = dbhelper.getAllData();
        String[] fromcolumns = new String[]{dataKasper.DBNAMECOLNAME};
        int[] toviews = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                fromcolumns,
                toviews,1);
        lv2.setAdapter(sca);

        lv2.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                dbhelper.deleteData(l);
                cursor = dbhelper.getAllData();
                sca.swapCursor(cursor);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Note! `onDestroy` closes the cursor when the activity ends. cursors should always be closed.

Comment: i did not create the id column in the table. i did store some data in database. now when i edit my table by adding _id column.And use it to delete the data then it  shows error :-  (1) no such column: _id
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Now i did create the new column name as primary key to the table but still i am unable to delete the selected item. when i delete each item of listview one by one then no one items are there in listview after exit from that activity but when i save new data and then click the button after saving data old data is also there in listview.please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Mamta, you need to update your question to include code as suggested by _Editing your question to include the code that instantiates the adapter and the code that creates the data source would enable a more specific answer to be given._. Although it does appear that you may not be handling refreshing the ListViews data (if you have not used `adapter.swapCursor()` or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your code, then that will be a issue as the ListView will be using the old data as it's basis).

Comment: when i try to delete item first time nothing happened  but when i try to delete the same item second time the item will delete but the app crash

Comment: pleas tell me why other methods should use accept deletedata

Comment: @Mamta I've added working/tested examples. I believe the reason that delete works at times is that it very much depends upon the data passed to it. It will work if the data passed matches the column in the database. It will do nothing if it does not match. This is compounded by the ListView displaying data which may in fact have been deleted, as the underlying ArrayLists are not changed when the Database is changed. The examples given fix these issues, the second includes an alternative using only a cursor.

Comment: my problem remain same.please help me.

Comment: i can delete all items after deleting each item but can't delete a single item.please tell me the solution.